# Running a terminal command every hour

Tags: macos, bash, shell, launchd

I'm trying to get my mac to run the `purge` command every hour by having the following `com.user.purge.plist` list in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.purge</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>purge</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Yet it doesn't seem to run it. Any idea why?**

**PS.** I have given my user nopassword privilege in sudoers as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs on [apple.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things could be going wrong here.

1) you need to properly set permissions on your launchdaemon files.

[Apple's TN2083 (Technote) states](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION43):

> When you install your daemon, make sure that you set the file system
>   permissions correctly. Apple recommends that daemons be owned by root,
>   have an owning group of wheel, and use permissions 755 (rwxr-xr-x) for
>   executables and directories, and 644 (rw-r--r--) for files.

2) have you tried loading your daemon via ["`launchctl`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html) yet?

try this:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.user.purge.plist
launchctl start /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.user.purge.plist
launchctl list
```

and see if it appears there